# Pass either a list or a value to a function in Python

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

What is the best way to be able to pass either a list or a value to a function and have it return as

`foo(x)`: `foo(x)`

`foo([x, y, z])`: `[foo(x), foo(y), foo(z)]`?

Is it just testing for whether the input is a list?  A try/except block trying to access list elements?  Something else?

Comment: You can use `type(x)` to define your logical flow

Comment: Or `isinstance(x, list)`

Comment: *"A try/except block trying to access list elements?"* - not if you want to take strings, which are also sequences. *"just testing for whether the input is a list?"* - not if you want to do proper duck typing. What are you actually trying to achieve? Could you give a more specific example? It sounds like you want something similar to `map`, which simply requires the second argument to be iterable (e.g. `map(int, 1)` will fail).

Answer (score 4):

use collections to determine if it is iterable or not. If iterable, do your list logic. If not do your variable logic

```
import collections

if isinstance(e, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(e, basestring) :
```

As pointed out in the comments. Add logic to not include strings

Comment: Or `MutableSequence`, if the function should mutate its arguments.

Comment: updated. just dont include string instances. should work for all iterables, and then logically divide out any edge cases

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple function `foo` that takes an element and multiplies it by two. If it's a list, it will return the list of `foo`-operated elements.

```
def foo(x):
    if isinstance(x, list): ## Accepts list ONLY
        return [foo(i) for i in x]
    return x * 2
```

Output:

```
>>> foo(3)
6
>>> foo([1,2,3])
[2, 4, 6]
```

### Edit:

Per Jon's comment, if you'd like a `tuple` to be acceptable input, you could do the following:

```
def foo(x):
    if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)): ## Accepts list OR tuple
        return [foo(i) for i in x]
    return x * 2
```

This will still return only a `list` for either a `list` or `tuple` input, though. If you want the same type of output as input (i.e. `tuple` output), then you can amend to the following:

```
def foo(x):
    if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)): ## Accepts list OR tuple
        result = [foo(i) for i in x]
        return result if not isinstance(x, tuple) else tuple(result)
    return x * 2
```

New output:

```
>>> foo(1)
2
>>> foo([1,2,3])
[2, 4, 6]
>>> foo((1,2,3))
(2, 4, 6)
```

Note also that this will handle odd nested structures:

```
>>> foo([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],(7,8,9)])
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], (14, 16, 18)]
```

Comment: And what about `foo((1, 2, 3))`? It doesn't fail, which the user might expect it to as you can't mutate the tuple, but instead returns something weird (`(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)`).

Comment: To be fair, he specifically asked for list... but I'll edit...

Comment: True, but you should at least comment on the limitations of the approach!